# What research is there into content of conversations vs IQ?

Tags: iq

I wonder if there is any research into the content of a conversation between two people and how that relates to IQ. My casual conversations are that people of, lets say a more humble background, which generally correlates to a lower IQ, the topics of conversation tend to involve:

- Food: What did you have for dinner.
- Drink: How many pints did you/will you have this evening/last night.
- Relations: Who said what to who, e.g. "He said.. then she said... then.."
- What you like: Do you like Jam? I like Jam. Do you like Marmalade? I like Marmalade.

i.e. fairly simple stuff. I don't think it would be too hard to program that into a computer. In fact, I would even say there is a lower form of conversation along the lines of:

"Alright?" "Aye" "Yup." "Aye". "Ow's it going?" "Aye. Good." "Yup". "Aye".

(Some might argue that such utterances actually have deeper meaning learned through years of use.)

Whereas I would characterise higher IQ conversations tend to involve more imagination, meta-language, "And then he said... but why? And what were the motives?" Critical thinking, and going against the grain. But then this could be because it's more socially acceptable to have these ideas, whereas in working class areas you don't want to be seen as different or above your station.

I don't think this is a class thing. Because you can have quite rich people whose conversations are quite simple. e.g. like the stereotype of the Valley Girl who just like talks about like clothes like thing like.